# how does the size of compiled binaries depend on the used libraries? c/c++

Tags: c++, c, gcc, iostream, stdio

Last week I found a simple game on the web called [killallcops.exe](http://www.auntiepixelante.com/killallcops/).
I studied the binaries and wondered why the programm is that big. (About 460k)

So I rewrote the game using iostream

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    std::cout << "All cops are killed.\nCongratulations";
    std::cin.ignore();
    return 0;
}
```

compiled it with g++ and got 460k too.

I really wondered why this thing was so big and rewrote it using stdio

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    printf("All cops are killed.\nCongratulations");
    while(getchar() != '\n'){}
    return 0;
}
```

compiled it with gcc and got 13k.

I know that iostream has much more abilities than stdio (like typesafety) and thus is itself much bigger, but why does this result in bigger binaries and are there solutions to reduce the size when using iostream, for example only using specific parts of it?

edit: as stated below using gcc 3.4.4 under cygwin

Comment: Can you show us the assembly it compiles to?

Comment: `<iostream>` has a lot of internal dependencies, even for using a simple `cout` call. It brings in a lot of other code/headers it needs to work (which includes template code and such). You can trust the compiler/linker to know what they're doing, but if you want to reduce the binary size, try using options like `gcc -s`, which strips symbols, or flags like `-Os` which attempts to optimize the binary for size. However, in nontrivial apps the size of bringing in `<iostream>` is not very significant.

Comment: @birryree: That could be an answer... :)

Comment: Are you using optimizations and stripping out symbols?

Comment: @walter you might be interested in [this quesion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1042773/gcc-c-hello-world-program-exe-is-500kb-big-when-compiled-on-windows-how/2250182#2250182)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll flesh out my comment as an answer:

`<iostream>` has a lot of internal dependencies, even for using a simple cout call. It brings in a lot of other code/headers it needs to work (which includes template code and such). Up front let's say the size of bringing in `<iostream>` is probably not very significant in a nontrivial application.

You can trust the compiler/linker to know what they're doing, but if you want to reduce the binary size, try using options like `gcc -s`, which strips symbols, or flags like `-Os` which attempts to optimize the binary for size.

I suspect a lot of your binary size problems actually comes from something else: a statically-linked `libstdc++`.

If you're using MinGW on Windows, do note that until very recently, their implementation of the GCC toolchain did not have a dynamically-linked `libstdc++`; instead all C++ builds statically link in `libstdc++` which will greatly increase the size of your binaries.

Here's a comparison, the size of a binary produced by `g++` for your code, on Linux, using GCC 4.6.1. No optimization or symbol stripping was performed on these builds.

```
λ > ls -lh a.out          
-rwxr-xr-x 1 billylee billylee 6.1K Dec 24 10:37 a.out
```

And here's one produced by GCC

```
λ > ls -lh trial
-rwxr-xr-x 1 billylee billylee 4.9K Dec 24 10:41 trial
```

The g++ version is a little larger than the gcc version, but not 100x larger.

edit: If you're using MinGW - there's a recent thread here: [How to reduce the size of executable produced by MinGW g++ compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973274/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-executable-produced-by-mingw-g-compiler)

MinGW gcc 4.5.0+ should use dynamic linking by default, check your version if you are using MinGW.

Comment: yes, i forgot to mention that i am using cygwin gcc. just checked, version 3.4.4 i will update and check back later. thanks for the explanation.

Comment: updating cygwin gcc was a bigger problem, but i tried it out on the universities linux box (mine electrocuted itself a few days ago) and get similar results now. thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't reproduce on Linux (sizes are 9K and 8K).  My guess is that for the C++ you are statically linking the standard library while for C you are dynamically linking it.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is: it isn't that big. Compiled on c++ 4.6 on Linux with no compile options it is 9040 bytes. After stripping it's 6312 bytes.

What compile options did you use and what version of g++ are you using?

It's possible that the size is due to your platform, perhaps if you are using MinGW and it is statically linking the runtime.

On a side note, `#import` is a deprecated g++ only extension to the language, you should be using `#include`

Comment: it indeed was include, was using too much java the last few days, so that error slipped in when writing the code from my memory.

Comment: @left if I recall, when you compile on linux by default the rtl isn't linked in statically where as on windows it is. So of course it's going to be smaller, it's not an equal comparision.