# windows c compiler generating large executables

Tags: c, windows, compiler-optimization, filesize

I was writing a c program for windows, and compiling it with: `cl test.c` and I noticed that the file size was 95744 bytes.

I thought that was strange so I began shortening the program to see if that would affect the size of the executable, but it stayed the same, I eventually just compiled an empty main function, with the same result, I attempted the same program on wsl2, compiling it with `gcc test.c -o test` and ran size on the elf which outputted:

```
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   1224     544       8    1776     6f0 test
```

does anyone know why this is or how to make the output smaller?

any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try adding `-O3` or `-Os` flags, enabling optimisations, the former for speed (but still reduces size), the latter for size explicitly (but still affects speed).

Comment: Also strip the debug symbols.

Comment: Static linking of libraries?

Comment: I'm attempting to make the windows executable smaller not the elf, sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reduce the size of executable produced by MinGW g++ compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7973274/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-executable-produced-by-mingw-g-compiler)

Comment: debug symbols - only link to pdb. maximum ~100h bytes. this is static linked crt

Comment: @RaymondChen No, I'm using the cl command in developer powershell.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 No, I'm not trying to reduce the file size on wsl, just on windows.

Comment: Try `/MD` for dynamically linked libc and `/O2` for optimization.

Comment: @Jason, /MD reduced the size of the output file down to 9216 bytes, could you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that `cl.exe` is statically linking libc by default meaning the C runtime library will be embedded into your executable.  That is where the bulk of the file size is coming from.  The option `/MD` will do a dynamic linking so these functions can be found at runtime.

Also, optimization options like `/O2` will also help to reduce the size of the resulting executable.

Comment: `/O2` does speed optimization. It'll reduce some space wasted for debugging purposes but it definitely won't produce binaries as small as `/Os`. But `/O2` or `/Ox` should be the default, not `/Os`

Comment: @phuclv True.  The implication being any optimization at all will be smaller than the default options.